# Unable to extend the MapActivity class?

Tags: java, android, api, google-maps

I'm implementing Google Maps on my app.

I have sourced my API key etc, and am currently following a coupe of tutorials. I need to extend the MapActivity superclass but I'm currently unable to do so.

I have implemented the map library in my manifest, along with inserting API key in my XML layout.

But still receieve a 'MapActivity cannot be resolved to a type' error.
Heres is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainMap"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
</application>
</manifest>
```

This is my XML:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<com.google.android.maps.MapView 
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="AIzaSyCJSfjl_7lU7-HKV3yIf5nnMODl6qiG2_g"
    />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

And my class:

```
package com.example.map;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainMap extends MapActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.maplayout);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.maplayout, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that your build target (e.g., Project > Properties > Android in Eclipse) is for a "Google APIs" version of the Android SDK.

Comment: As simple as that many thanks commonWare. Will mark your answer as correct when I am able

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

You select **project built target** is Google APIs using your project properties